# How do I push data from hub to client every second using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Working on building signalR hub,  I'm able to get data from hub to the client but I'm, not sure how do I push it every 1 second.

I'm not sure where do I set the timer in the controller where `getApps` method exists or in the hub?

Hub:

```
public class nphub : Hub
{
    public readonly sbController _sbcontroller;

    public nphub(sbController sbcontroller)
    {
        _sbcontroller = sbcontroller;
    }

    public async Task NotifyConnection()
    {
        IActionResult result = await _sbcontroller.getApps();
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("TestBrodcasting", result);
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getApps()
{
    // var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps");
    // var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
    // var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Ok($"Testing a Basic HUB at {DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}");
}
```

Client:

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/nphub").build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    TestConnection();
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

function TestConnection() {
    connection.invoke("NotifyConnection").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}

connection.on("TestBrodcasting", function (time) {
    document.getElementById('broadcastDiv').innerHTML = time.value;
    document.getElementById('broadcastDiv').style.display = "block";
});
```

Just for the test purpose to see realtime changes, I'm trying to return time. I'm able to see time on the client but it's not changing.

Comment: Why do you want to push data *every second*? The point of SignalR is that you don't need to do that. You only need to push data when it changes.

Comment: It depends on what the data is and how you check it. For example, if the data is a table in a database, you might utilize a [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency). Or it could be the result of a message being added to queue. Or a user posting a chat message.

Comment: how do I do that? in this time is changing continuously still I'm not able to see that on screen

Comment: I'm working on the dashboard which needs data to be pulled from API, how do I get a continuous stream of data in this case

Comment: Ideally that API would have some mechanism to subscribe to changes so that it can push updates to you, rather than you having to poll. Assuming it doesn't have that, then you'll need to write some code that hits that API, decides if the data has changed since your previous polling attempt, and thus decide whether it needs to push an update out via the hub to the connected clients.

Comment: @mason that's what I'm asking how do I call the api from hub :)

Comment: You wouldn't call it *from* the hub. You'd write some code that calls the API and gets the result, then that code can call into the hub, which then calls methods on the clients. Chris showed you how to do that below.

Comment: @mason `getApps` is the method which pulls the data from API, but I'm not sure how do I call `getApps` method from service mentioned by @Chris and the send it to hub. Because `getapps` is the one method I showed here there are 12 didderent calls to api and they all needs to be called.

Comment: Like, do I need to inject IHostedServices into the controller?

Comment: You just....call it.  Just call the method from inside the DoWork method that he created. DoWork will get called by the timer at intervals of 1 second. That's where you need to implement your logic for calling API's and then calling into the hub when appropriate. None of this has anything to do with a controller. It's a hosted service. Chris helpfully linked to the docs for it. Actually read his answer. Try the code.

Comment: @mason I'm not sure how do I call controller method from IHostedService, can you please point me in right direction?

Comment: You know how to create an instance of an object, right? You know how to call a method on an instance of an object, right? So I don't really understand why you're asking this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a hosted service, as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks). Add a class like:

```
internal class SignalRTimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IHubContext<nphub> _hub;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public SignalRTimedHostedService(IHubContext<nphub> hub, ILogger<SignalRTimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is working.");
        // send message using _hub
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*Note: A hosted service lives in singleton scope. You can inject `IHubContext<T>` directly, though, because it too is in singleton scope.*

Then in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHostedService<SignalRTimedHostedService>();
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic solution